# What are the criteria for receiving a bounty if it is not manually awarded?

Tags: support, bounty

Realizing that I'm running the risk of sounding extremely petty, I'm confused and curious enough that I have to ask. :)  There was [a question with a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27990/how-can-i-get-multitouch-enabled-on-my-sentelic-touchpad-msi-x350-notebook) of 50.  I answered this question after the bounty was placed, and my answer had two upvotes and was the highest ranked answer at the time the bounty ended.

It was my understanding that in this situation, having met [the criteria in the last bullet point](https://askubuntu.com/faq#bounty) about bounties, my answer would have automatically been awarded half of the bounty, as no other answer was chosen.  Since this didn't happen, I obviously seem to be missing something, and I'd like to understand more about how bounties work.

Comment: Hmm, unless someone worked some magic without commenting here, it looks like the issue took care of itself after 30-40 minutes.  I just assumed that the bounty would be applied immediately after the bounty period was over. A moderator can feel free to close this unless they think it might be of use to someone in the future.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Auto-awarding of expired bounties happens in a scheduled job that (currently) runs every hour, so it may take up to 60 minutes until the bounty is awarded.